# Error: Identifier "cout" is undefined. <iostream> included and using namespace std;

Tags: c++, undefined, cout

I am trying to `cout` some variables but the compiler says that `cout is undefined`. I have included iostream and am using namespace std. Removing `using namespace std` and `using std::cout` instead changes the issue to "namespace "std" has no member "cout" ". I found some answers saying to add `# include "stdafx.h"` to the code but `Error: cannot open source file "stdafx.h"` occurs.

Code is:

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Complex::Complex(int PolarOrRectang, float RealOrArg, float ImagOrAng) {
    if (PolarOrRectang == 0) {
        real = RealOrArg;
        imag = ImagOrAng;
    else {
        real = RealOrArg * cos(ImagOrAng);
        imag = RealOrArg * sin(ImagOrAng);
    }
};

void Complex::getValue(int PolarOrRectang) {
    if (PolarOrRectang == 0) {
        cout << real << " +_" << imag << "i" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << sqrt((real^2) + (imag^2)) << "*e^-" << atan(imag / real)<< endl;
    }
};
```

I'm trying to define a class, so my main is elsewhere.
Running a very basic program that just couts "hello world" works fine, the problem is specific to this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `#include<iostream>` at the first position, the order is important

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
```

PS: Why do you use std:: when you are using "using namespace std;"?

Comment: sorry, forgot to edit that out. I've tried using one or the other separately but neither works

Comment: Ty to put #include<iostream> at the first position, maybe the order is important

Comment: Actually, `#include "Complex.h"` *should* be the first line of `"Complex.cpp"`; The error is not putting the includes the header needs *inside* the header.